# WEB API Kedo Grid with Grouping

Tags: asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, grouping

I am new at using Kendo .
I have searched all over but could not see any hint on using group on kendo grid , with server/client side grouping.

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TemperatureRecord>()
    .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(temperatureRecord => temperatureRecord.RecordId).Width(100);
                 columns.Bound(temperatureRecord => temperatureRecord.MemberIdentity).Width(150);
          columns.Bound(temperatureRecord => temperatureRecord.Location);
          columns.Bound(temperatureRecord => temperatureRecord.TemperatureCelcius).Width(200);
          columns.Bound(temperatureRecord => temperatureRecord.Remark).Width(300);
      })
      .Groupable(g => g.Enabled(false))
      .ToolBar(toolbar =>
      {
          toolbar.Save(); 
      })
      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridEditMode.InCell)) 
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .WebApi()
     .Batch(true) // Enable batch updates
     .Group(groups => groups.Add(temperatureRecord => temperatureRecord.MemberIdentity))
     .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(temperatureRecord => temperatureRecord.RecordId); 

            })
    .Read(read => read.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "TemperatureRecord" })))
    .Update(update => update.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "TemperatureRecord" })))
    )
    )
```

The code which I have do not show any error on screen but it hangs.
Same thing happens when I manually group the grid on browser.. It hangs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a number of tries , I discovered that Model needs to be added on the field which you want to group.

Changed the code to following and it worked

```
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<IHiS.Noss.Web.Models.TemperatureRecord>()
            .Name("grid")

                .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(temperatureRecord => temperatureRecord.RecordId).Width(100).Hidden(true);

                  columns.Bound(temperatureRecord => temperatureRecord.MemberIdentity).Width(150).Groupable(true).Hidden(true);
                  columns.Bound(temperatureRecord => temperatureRecord.Location).Width(100);
                  columns.Bound(temperatureRecord => temperatureRecord.TemperatureCelcius).Width(200);
                  columns.Bound(temperatureRecord => temperatureRecord.Remark).Width(300);
              })


              .Groupable(g => g.Enabled(false))
              .ToolBar(toolbar =>
              {
                  toolbar.Save(); // The "save" command saves the changed data items
              })
              .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridEditMode.InCell)) // Use in-cell editing mode


            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource

            .WebApi()
            .ServerOperation(false)
             .Batch(true) // Enable batch updates

            .Group(groups => groups.Add(temperatureRecord => temperatureRecord.MemberIdentity))
             .Model(model =>
                    {
                        model.Id(temperatureRecord => temperatureRecord.RecordId); // Specify the property which is the unique identifier of the model
                        model.Field(temperatureRecord => temperatureRecord.MemberIdentity);
                    })

            .Read(read => read.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "TemperatureRecord" })).Data("getdate"))
            .Update(update => update.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "TemperatureRecord" })))

            )
       )
```